# Преобразование и LINQ

Tags: c#

Можно как то выполнять преобразования с помощью `LINQ` ? Чтобы получилось что то вроде этого.

- Получить список преобразованных
- Получить элемент со свойством равному параметру

**Не рабочий код, результат фантазии:**

```
var test = _myInteraceList.FindAll(i => i is MyClass1)
                          .SingleOrDefault(c => c.MyProperty == myParametr);
```

Comment: `_myInteraceList.OfType<MyClass1>().SingleOrDefault(c => c.MyProperty == myParametr)` ?

Comment: @iikuzmychov то что нужно! спасибо большое!!!

Comment: @iikuzmychov лучше ответом, если помогло. Так легче найти потом будет

Comment: @iikuzmychov ок, понял, оформлю - не хотел лавры забирать)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подошёл ответ из комментария от @iikuzmychov

Чтобы получить кокретный экземпляр из интерфейсного списка со свойством равным параметру:

```
_interfaces.OfType<ConcretClass>().SingleOrDefault(c => c.Prop == param);
```

Или можно ещё так:

```
_interfaces.SingleOrDefault(i => i is ConcretClass c && c.Prop == param);
```